# Having trouble to update a list of object references in the DB in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to Edit a list of object references in my Cinema controller like this -

```
public ActionResult Save(Cinema cinema)
{
    var cinemaInDb = _context.Cinemas.Include(c => c.Seats).Single(c => c.Id == cinema.Id);

    cinemaInDb.Name = cinema.Name;
    cinemaInDb.Address = cinema.Address;
    cinemaInDb.NumberOfSeats = cinema.NumberOfSeats;
    cinemaInDb.Seats = SetSeats(cinemaInDb);
    cinemaInDb.OpeningHourId = cinema.OpeningHourId;
    cinemaInDb.ClosingHourId = cinema.ClosingHourId;

    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

As you can see, I'm getting the *already existing* Cinema from the database and I'm overwriting new data to it.

Everything works just fine, the only problem is that the Seats property (Which is a list of object references, meaning that each seat is a different entity, having its own ID and values) doesn't delete the old seats in the database, It just nullifies them and adding new seats to the list.

So, if I have a cinema with 10 seats and I want to edit it to now have 5 seats, it will nullify the 10 seats and add 5 new seats. When debugging everything looks fine, the cinemaInDb.Seats property is getting the values I want, the problem is just inside the database. I tried clearing the list before adding anything to it, but it didn't help.

Just in case, here is my SetSeats function -

```
public List<Seat> SetSeats(Cinema cinema)
        {
            List<Seat> Seats = new List<Seat>();
            char rowLetter = 'A';
            int seatNumInRow = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= cinema.NumberOfSeats; i++, seatNumInRow++)
            {
                Seats.Add(new Seat
                {
                    Id = i - 1,
                    CinemaId = cinema.Id,
                    Cinema = cinema,
                    Location = "" + rowLetter + seatNumInRow,
                    isAvailable = true
                });
                if ((i % 10) == 0)
                {
                    rowLetter++;
                    seatNumInRow = 0;
                }
            };
            return Seats;
        }
```

And my Seat Model -

```
public class Seat
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int? CinemaId { get; set; }

        public Cinema Cinema { get; set; }

        //public byte ScreeningId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Location { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool isAvailable { get; set; }

        public Seat()
        {
            isAvailable = true;
        }
    }
```

It just creates a list of seats according to the number of seats chosen by the user when filling the form. In this function I'm giving each seat a location because later I want to create a map of the cinema where the user can choose his desired seat.

Comment: Show `SetSeats()`, more than likely your problem is there or  your mapping.

Comment: As I said - the SetSeats function returns the values I want. This is the same function I use when I'm creating a new Cinema, which works great for me. When saving the changes to the database, the cinemaInDb object reference is as I want it to be. There are no unnecessary seats. But then ONLY in the database, the old seats aren't deleted, only nullified.

Comment: You say you have issue with the Seats property, @mxmissile is asking you rightfully to show the `SetSeats()` because that is the method who set this `Seats` property that is causing the issue :) You see the issue? If you do not show this method we cannot tell you what is wrong because in your code actually there is nothing except that method who manipulate the `Seats` property...

Comment: The code was too long for a comment so I have updated my question, hope it helps :)